# jqGrid drag and drop column reorder

Tags: jquery

I've seen example of jqGrid does drag & drop column [reordering](http://www.trirand.net/examples/functionality/column_reorder_resize/default.aspx). However, the feature is not documented anywhere in the jqGrid [Wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs), or maybe I overlooked or something. Does anyone know how to implement this in jqGrid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it. Need to add 'sortable:true'.

Comment: Note: You also need to embed jquery-ui for that, else it remains unsortable !

Comment: Do you know how to detect when a sort operation is completed (when a column is finished being dragged and 'dropped')?